# What is wrong with func NamedExec?

Tags: go, sqlx

**go version**:   `1.14.6`
**sqlx version**: `latest`

**wrong code as follow:**

```golang
test := Test{
  Name: "John",
  Age:  30,
  Id:   "bskdvfjreo018g2c5pqg",
}
// table test has fields: id, name, age
_, err := sqlxdb.DB.NamedExec("NSERT INTO test(name,age,id)VALUES(:Name,:Age,:Id)", &test)
log.Println(err)

// log as follow:

// 2020/08/07 11:49:15 could not find name Name in &sqlx.Test{Id:"bskdvfjreo018g2c5pqg", Name:"John", CreateAt:0, Age:30}
```

Dose anyone knows whether or not the second parameter of `NamedExec` must pass value like ":create_at" but not like ":CreateAt" and so one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [`jmoiron/sqlx` issue 419](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/419), check if adding json field name mapping (using [struct field tag](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)) would help:

```
type User struct {
  Id        int       `json:"id"`
  Name      string    `json:"name"`
  Bio       string    `json:"about,omitempty"`
  Active    bool      `json:"active"`
  Admin     bool      `json:"-"`
  CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}
```

Then see if passing `&test` to `NamedExec` will result in `NamedExec` using `:created_at` instead of `:CreatedAt`

Comment: Thanks, VonC. Maybe i didn't express it clearly. My core question is: A golang struct `Test` has field named `CreateAt` which Corresponds to the field `create_at` of the table `test` in the database. While using NamedExec of sqlx, the placeholder just to be  ":CreateAt", not ":create_at", or ":FilePath", not":file_path". Then how to achieve it?

Comment: @carmeltop I understand, For now, most usage of NamedExec I can see included lowercase fields indeed.

Comment: @carmeltop I have rewritten the answer with a possible solution to test.